# how can I set different areas for groups of nodes run as RandomWaypoint movement in one-simulator

Tags: java, networking, one-simulator

I set three groups of nodes and all of them run as RandomWaypoint movement,but I can't let them run in different areas. how can I set different area for nodes to move in for different group?

I've tried to set worldSize,mapFile,routeFile and so on of the group,but they didn't work.

```
Group6.groupID = t
Group6.bufferSize = 50M
Group6.movementModel = RandomWaypoint
movementModel6.worldSize = 200,200

RandomWaypoint.mapFile = data/my1.wkt
RandomWaypoint.worldSize = 200,200
Group6.worldSize = 200,200
Group6.routeFile  = data/my1.wkt

#Group6.routeType = 2
Group6.waitTime = 10, 30
Group6.speed = 7, 10
Group6.nrofHosts = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic RandomWaypoint module does not support that kind of functionality. The best way to do this would be to implement a new movement module based on the RandomWaypoint that has this capability.

Alternatively, if you want to use map-based mobility, for example the [MapBasedMovement](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/c9404f105268109cc9a7269c51f756514885f62e/src/movement/MapBasedMovement.java#L56) has option "okMaps" to select which maps should be used by which node groups.